# Representing 2^1024 as a floating-point number

Tags: floating-point

Can 2^1024  be represented with a built-in floating-point type, such as double or long-double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can 2^1024 be represented with a built-in floating-point type, such as double or long-double?

2<sup>1024</sup> has the value of 1.797693134862315907729...*10<sup>308</sup>

The following is able to print the approximate value of 2<sup>1024</sup> as a `long double`.  Yet this value commonly exceeds the maximum finite `double`: `DBL_MAX`.  The ability to represent 2<sup>1024</sup> is *implementation dependent*.  The following is a common implementation.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  long double two1024 = powl(2,1024);
  printf("2^1024  %.21Le\n", two1024);
  printf("DBL_MAX %.21Le\n", DBL_MAX*1.0L);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
                         v----- Difference begins here
2^1024  1.797693134862315907729e+308
DBL_MAX 1.797693134862315708145e+308
```

Notes:
C only requires that `LDBL_MAX >= DBL_MAX >= 1.0e+37`.
`DBL_MAX` commonly is the the maximum finite value of [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) or ~1.7976931348623157...e+308.
On some systems the `long double` range matches the `double` range.

Comment: There is a standard C function especially for multiplying by powers of 2, `ldexpl`. So `powl(2, 1024)` can be `ldexpl(1, 1024)`. (Although it should not matter on an implementation with a good `powl` or one that optimizes `powl(2, n)` to `ldexpl(1, n)` or that optimizes `powl(2, 1024)` to `0x1p1024l`.)

Answer (score 2):

2^1024 is greater than the largest floating point value representable by IEEE with 64bit machines.

2^1024 =

```
17976931348623159077293051907890247336179769789423065727343008115773267580550096313270847
73224075360211201138798713933576587897688144166224928474306394741243777678934248654852763
02219601246094119453082952085005768838150682342462881473913110540827237163350510684586298
239947245938479716304835356329624224137216
```

Maximum IEEE floating point, approx 1.7977*10^308 =

0 11111111110 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111(b) =

```
17976931348623157081452742373170435679807056752584499659891747680315726078002853876058955
86327668781715404589535143824642343213268894641827684675467035375169860499105765512820762
45490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723
168738177180919299881250404026184124858368
```

These numbers have a difference of:

```
19958403095347198116563727130368385660674512604354575415025472424372118918689640657849579
65492635701089342446844192495243972437988393593660739171798284831420320005672951085676517
53772144436298718265335674454392399333081045512087038888885526844804415750712090687575604
16423584952303440099278848
```

That is the maximum IEEE number because the 64 bits are broken down as the following:

```
1 - sign
11 - exponent
52 - mantissa, or value
```

With the double precision type, the exponent bias is 1023. Note that: 11111111110(b) = 2046(d). 2046 - 1023 = 1023. This is just shy of the 1024 you would need to store 2^1024 and why 2^1023 works fine.